# Unity Light Bug

Tags: unity, camera, lighting, shadows

I saw this while testing my game.

I have a light situated behind the Main Camera.
All is working perfect, until I get a Game Over, and changes to the Game Over scene. From then, all lights have no effect and all is darker than usually, even the Game Over Scene (if we zoom out in the editor while playing), and when we play again with the Game Over scene button.

Non Bugged
[image]

Bugged
[image]

I don't have any light-related script and my light source's properties are:

> Type: Directional
> Color: FFFFFF
> Mode: Realtime
> Intensity: 1
> Indirect Multiplier: 1
> Shadow Type: No Shadows
> Cookie: None
> Cookie Size: 10
> Draw Halo: False
> Flare: None
> Render Mode: Auto
> Culling Mask: Everything

I think this is a Unity bug. But there is a way to solve this?

Comment: Do you observe this effect in a built executable, or only in the editor? I've found that baked light is not correctly displayed after a scene transition in the editor, but it works correctly when built into a player-facing version.

Comment: In the editor it's bugged but in a build it's fine. also I noticed that doesen't matter if it's realtime, baked or mixed, all will give the same result. There is a way to solve that problem, or we have to wait for Unity to pull an update that solves this bug? @DMGregory